# Display a holo light option menu icon

Tags: android, android-menu

I use the following styles to style my ActionBar:

```
<style name="Theme.Bloodpressure" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Bloodpressure</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Bloodpressure" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_bloodpressure</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_bloodpressure</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_bar_title_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/np_top_margin</item>
  </style>
```

I am being displayed the following menu icon:
[image]

How do I show the holo light menu icon instead of the current black one?

Comment: Your current icon _is_ the Holo Light overflow icon.

Comment: Why the hell is this tagged as "Java"?

Comment: @Ole I am sorry, I mean I want the white color instead of the gray one. That color looks disabled with the background color.

Comment: @MGorgon There I changed it!!!

Comment: @MGorgon If you see a question with wrong tags, edit it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current icon *is* the `Holo Light` overflow icon.

You can override the overflow button style of the `Holo Light`-theme with `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle`

```
<style name="Theme.Bloodpressure" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Bloodpressure</item>

    /* Use Holo Dark style for the overflow icon*/
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@android:style/ActionBar.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```